# Change/Update part of string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, string-concatenation

Sorry for my bad English.
I need to change parts of a string in some rows in the table `ifns_code` from ('before'):

```
name  fio
3301 <a href="127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/lrm" title="LRM (1641)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">3301</img></a>  
3302 <a href="127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/lrm" title="LRM (1641)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">3302</img></a>  
3303 <a href="127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/uaa" title="uaa (1600)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">3303</img></a>  
5007 <a href="127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/uaa" title="uaa (1600)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">5007</img></a>  
5004 <a href="127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/meal" title="meal (1570)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">5004</img></a>
```

to ('after'):

```
name fio
3301 <a href="127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/lrm" title="LRM (1641)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">3301</img></a>  
3302 <a href="127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/lrm" title="LRM (1641)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">3302</img></a>  
3303 <a href="127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/lrm" title="LRM (1641)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">3303</img></a>  
5007 <a href="127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/lrm" title="LRM (1641)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">5007</img></a>  
5004 <a href="127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/lrm" title="LRM (1641)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">5004</img></a>
```

In other words:
I need an sql query that changes only parts of a string in selected records:

```
where 'name' in ('3303','5007','5004')
```

change:

```
<a href="https://127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/**!!!**" title="**!!!**">
```

to:

```
<a href="https://127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/lrm"" title="LRM (1641)">
```

without touching this part of string:

```
<img src="../images/staff.ico">**!!!**</img></a>
```

I'm trying to make this with SUBSTRING_INDEX and CONCAT, but my knowledge of sql queries is not good.

Comment: What you need is a `REPLACE` function that works *only* on the first two occurrences of `**!!!**` and not on the third one. Tricky ... It would be simpler, if the third target was something else, like `**???**`. Is that doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE ifns_code INNER JOIN
( SELECT name n, REPLACE(fio,'**!!!**</img>','**???**</img>') f FROM ifns_code ) t ON n=name
SET ifns_code.fio=REPLACE(REPLACE(f,'**!!!**',code),'**???**',name)
```

This will do both replace operations, first the three letter code (whose name I don't know, I have used `code` as a name) and then the `name`. If you want to leave the last `**!!!**` instance to remain as it is, just replace `name` with `**!!!**` in the outer `REPLACE`function.

**Edit:**

Now, having a clear description of what you want, I can provide you with the desired `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE ifns_code INNER JOIN (
  SELECT name n,instr(fio,'Profile/') i,instr(fio,'"><img') j FROM ifns_code 
) tbl ON n=name 
SET fio=CONCAT(substring(fio,1,i+7),
               'lrm" title="LRM (1641)',
               substring(fio,j))
WHERE name IN ('3303','5007','5004')
```

see here for a live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/3c1a4/1

In the derived table expression I evaluate the positions before (`i`) and after (`j`) the string portion I want to change. The rest is just a combination of `substring` and `concat`.

Comment: Maybe i'm not very good explain my problem. i'm need change a few rows, i don't know which user will be in this rows, maybe 'meal' or 'lrm' or 'uaa'. Need change any of this names to 'lrm' in two places in the string: Profile/uaa" title="uaa (1600) to  Profile/lrm" title="lrm (1641). Ending of the string must not be changed <img src="../images/staff.ico">5007 (or 5004 or 3301 etc.)</img></a>

Comment: Could you maybe clarify, how your data looks right at the start? The table shown in your post appears to be the final state, i.e. the output, you *want* to have, after the update. Is that the case?

Comment: Table in the question, it's real table, not final. finale must be
3301  <a href="https://127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/lrm" title="LRM (1641)"><img     src="../images/staff.ico">3301</img></a>
3302  <a href="https://127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/lrm" title="LRM (1641)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">3302</img></a>
3303  <a href="https://127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/lrm" title="LRM (1641)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">3303</img></a>
5007  <a href="https://127.0.0.1/Users/Profile/lrm" title="LRM (1641)"><img src="../images/staff.ico">5007</img></a>